# Is it possible to handle hardlink with Qt5?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am currently modifying a Qt application which uses the `bool QFile::link(const QString &linkName)` function.

This function creates a link that points to the file `linkName` and the type of the link depends on the underlying systems.

The underlying system we use is Linux (Buildroot distribution) and by default the link created is a symlink.

I would like to know if someone did manage to force Qt to create hardlink rather than symbolic link ?

Answer (score 0):

Qt has no API whatsoever (public or private) for creating hardlinks. You will need to use a native API instead. For Linux, that would be [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html).